# "I saw john the other day" ,What is "the other day"

Tags: phrase-meaning, adjectives

Please take a look at the sentence

> I saw john the other day

I know the meaning of "the other day"  But is it a object (noun phrase). because **"day"** is a noun,**"other"** is adjective, and **"the"** is article. So i think it could be a object (noun phrase)

But **the other day** is just similar to **every day** which is an adverb

For example

> I see him everyday
>
> I runs everyday

I think **everyday** is adverb here because it describing the verb. Similarly in first sentence  "the other day" also works in same way.

So in first sentence what is "the other day" ? is it a object(noun phrase) or an adverb ?

Comment: I think you call it a *time adverbial*.

Comment: The grammatical issue is pretty well addressed.  But if it's important, "the other day" doesn't mean "every day".  It's an expression that means a recent day or "recently".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of word classes, it's a noun phrase. Syntactically, it's a (time) adverbial, not an object.

Comment: @beginner Why do think it's an adjective. Does it modify any noun?

Comment: @user178049 Sorry, I meant adverb.

Comment: Basically "the other day" is "noun phrase" works as a adverb(time),got it. @user178049 , ParaDice Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Just don't mix up word classes (which, as the name suggests, happens at the level of individual words) and syntactical categories (which look at groups of words and their relations in the sentence).

Comment: ParaDiceThanks for great advice, I think now my concept is more clear.  Please assure me .  we have a sentence, "I works in Delhi", So If we see "delhi" as a word it is noun , But we see role of "in delhi" in sentence. It is an adjective. Am i right ?

Comment: @beginner "in Delhi" is an adverbial, but an adjective. Adverbials are those parts of the sentence that give you additional information, e.g. about time, place or frequency of the events described in the sentence.

Comment: Now i am totally confused . We use adverb to tell the place , And use adjective for attributes of noun. So "in delhi" describing the place.So it must be a adverb. How can "in delhi" be an adjective .? please explain

Comment: Do not mix up adverbs and adverbials! Again: adverbs are types of individual words, adverbials are a phenomenon from syntax. Read up on both and you'll understand the difference. ;)

Comment: @ParaDice, Thank you so much. I understand now . adverbs are single words.  "in delhi"(preposition phrase) is just like adverbs , but it contains two words so if we use more than two words  to describe time, place,why, etc We call them adverbials. but adverbials not contain adjectives. So we can call "in delhi" an adverbials only , It is not an adjective. adverbials are explained very well on http://pediaa.com/difference-between-adverb-and-adverbial/

Comment: You got it. :)       .